# Domain of log and its derivative

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)=log(x)$ then the domain of function $f(x)$ will be $(0,\infty)$. 
My question is that what will be the domain of its derivative  $f'(x)=1/x $? 
I think It should not be $(-\infty,+\infty)-\{0\}$ since  the function $f(x)$ is not  defined for $x$ less than $0$ and so $f'(x)$ cannot have any existence.

Comment: Did you mean to write $(0,\infty)$? The derivative clearly can't exist where the function being differentiated doesn't exist.

Comment: The domain of the derivative of a function, by the very definition of derivative, is contained in the domain of the starting function. If you want to talk about maximal domains, then that's a different matter. Also note that the domain of the derivative of $\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \log(|x|)$ is $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Your function is define on the interval $ (0,\infty ) $ only. In particular, by definition of the derivative is defined on $ (0,\infty ) $

Comment: I just want to know whether I am thinking of the issue in right way. Will it mean that domain derivative equals domain of original function intersect domain of function which is represented by the derivative?

Comment: ln(x) isn't an elementary function which is most likely why there is so much confusion. So when you take the derivative of this function, most people say its 1/x. This is mostly correct, however you have to only use values of x that exist for BOTH ln(x) and 1/x. 1/x is just an extrapolation, which most likely has its own uses...